# First java program, does not print anything

Tags: java

I think I wrote the code correctly, but it does not print anything. Can anyone explain me why ?

```
public class Dogs {

    String name = "";
    String color = "";
    String breed = "";
    boolean hungry = true;

    void changeBarking (boolean True) {
        hungry = True;
    }

    void changeName (String newValue) {
        name = newValue;
    }

    void changeBreed (String newValue) {
        breed = newValue;
    }

    void changeColor (String newValue) {
        color = newValue;
    }

    void printStates() {
        System.out.println("name:" + name);
        System.out.println("color:" + color);
        System.out.println("breed:" + breed);
        System.out.println("hungry:" + hungry);
    }

}

class DogsDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Dogs dog1 = new Dogs();
        Dogs dog2 = new Dogs();

        dog1.changeName("Dogas");
        dog1.changeColor("Juodas");
        dog1.changeBarking(true);

        dog2.changeName("Taksas");
        dog2.changeColor("Rudas");
        dog2.changeBarking(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would it print anything?

Comment: If you don't call .printStates() it's hard.

Comment: I dont know why nobody is mentioning it, but wouldnt it be better to a) delete the printStates() method and move the print commands to the main method by calling `dog1.variableName` or b) overriding the toString method of the dog class...? Just a design hint anyway..

Comment: Overriding toString() would be better IMO, but accessing the variable directly like `dog1.variableName` kinda goes against OO encapsulation principles. Those members should be `private` with setters/getters.

Answer (score 9):

You have to actually call the method that does the printing.

Add

```
dog1.printStates();
dog2.printStates();
```

This seems a little awkward as well:

```
void changeBarking (boolean True) {
     hungry = True;
}
```

Variable names should start with a lowercase, and calling a boolean variable `True` is bound to cause confusion. Instead use something like this:

```
void changeBarking (boolean isBarking) {
     hungry = isBarking;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you are not calling method `printStates()`.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding the lines

```
dog1.printStates();
dog2.printStates();
```

in your main() method after you set all your values. Currently you never actually make a call to your printing method.

Answer (score 1):

System.out.println(""); allows you to print String. It's what you're doing in the printStates() method, but since you're not calling it at any time, it is not executed.

Answer (score 0):

Because You are not calling the methd `printStates()`

Call the method as

```
dog1.printStates();
dog2.printStates();
```

Answer (score 0):

The static before the main method, this declares the method as a class method, which means it needs no instance to be called. So as you are going to call a non static method, Java complains because you are trying to call a so called "instance method", which, of course needs an instance first.

Just call  `dog1.printStates();` and  `dog2.printStates();`inside main method .

```
class DogsDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       //  code here
        dog1.printStates();
        dog2.printStates();
    }
}
```

See this simple program:http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/366637/calling-methods-from-main-method